# Answered a question; Can anyone untick the answer?

Tags: discussion

This user asked a question, I did answer according to his question scope perfectly, and he upvoted and ticked my answer because it is according to his header and description of the question. But a few minutes later he unticked the question and asked another question in comments out of his question scope, so my query for you is that,

1. Can anyone untick the answer and add more and more scope on a single question?
2. Should I tell him to tick that question again and ask another related to that scope?

**His entered tags are 'HTML' and 'CSS'. But then he asked me about PHP.**

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: I would ignore the edits, flag the substantial changes to the question to a moderator, and refuse to update the answer.  Authors that change their question in this way will continue to do that, there is no end to it, seen it many times

Comment: Re *"Is anyone can untick"*: It is incomprehensible. Do you mean *"Can anyone untick"*? You can [edit your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/401516/edit).

Comment: Well, they can untick your answer at any time, and if they ask about something unrelated to the question, then you are free to tell them to ask a new question.